# Sort columns with numbers and string

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have 2 functions for sort columns, with "%" the columns are sorted, but if I use a letter instead of "%" the columns sort alphabetically.

In `main.js` I use this for select the options, `paint2` works but `paint1` not works:

```
var func = (upti == 'T') ? paint1 : paint2;
[...]
str += '<td>' + func(value[firstvalue]) + '</td>';
```

And in other file I have these functions:

```
function paint1(tmp) {
  if (tmp == null || tmp == "null" || tmp == "-") {
    return "-";
  } else if (tmp == "Out") {
    return tmp;
  } else {
    tmp = (+tmp).toFixed(1);    
    return "<span>" + tmp + "s</span>";
  }
}

function paint2(disp) {
  if (disp == null || disp == "null" || disp == "-") {
    return "-";
  } else if (disp == "Out") {
    return disp;
  } else if (disp == "100") {
    disp = parseFloat(disp);
    return disp.toFixed(1) + "<span>%</span>";
  } else {
    disp = parseFloat(disp);
    return disp.toFixed(2) + "<span>%</span>";
  }
}
```

Comment: please add some example data for sorting - and the wanted result of them.

Comment: Nothing on the question, Have you tried angularjs? It makes these things a breeze

Comment: @Gary are you trying to kill mosquitos with a riffle?

Comment: Your JS code is also incomplete. What does the `value` array hold?

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping table to replace letters with percent signs:

```
function replacer(match, offset, fullstring)
  { 
  /* Store position of replacement */
  replacer[match] = offset;
  return "%";
  }

function sorter(seq)
  {
  var result = seq.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, replacer);
  return result;
  }
```